# Cannot read file from google drive programmatically android?

Tags: android, android-studio, google-drive-api, google-drive-android-api, google-drive-realtime-api

Sign on google account is success, but when i  try to get file on google drive always Fail with error show like this **"com.google.android.gms.common.api.ApiException: 8: API failed to connect while resume"**. I have read this link too [enter link description here](https://github.com/gsuitedevs/android-samples/tree/71105dc51d466d4892e3798fcaa8cdde06e34a07/app/src/main/java/com/google/android/gms/drive/sample/demo). But there is no solution. this is my code. And i have register my application on google console.
**Gradle**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.pripun.application"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 21
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:11.8.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-drive:11.8.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.8.0'
}
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="9" android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_CREDENTIALS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

    <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

    <activity android:name=".GoogleDr" android:screenOrientation="portrait" >

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />

        </intent-filter>

    </activity>
</application>
```

**GoogleDR.java**

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.Auth;
import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignIn;
import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignInAccount;
import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignInClient;
import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignInOptions;
import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignInResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
import com.google.android.gms.drive.Drive;
import com.google.android.gms.drive.DriveClient;
import com.google.android.gms.drive.DriveResourceClient;
import com.google.android.gms.drive.MetadataBuffer;
import com.google.android.gms.drive.query.Filters;
import com.google.android.gms.drive.query.Query;
import com.google.android.gms.drive.query.SearchableField;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnFailureListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnSuccessListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;

/**
 * Created by Akbar on 3/22/2018.
 */

public class GoogleDr extends AppCompatActivity {
    private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
    private static final int RC_SIGN_IN = 7;
    private String TAG = "Hasil SIGN";
    private static final int REQUEST_CODE_SIGN_IN = 0;
    private static final int REQUEST_CODE_CAPTURE_IMAGE = 1;
    private static final int REQUEST_CODE_CREATOR = 2;
    private DriveClient mDriveClient;
    private DriveResourceClient mDriveResourceClient;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.googledr);
        signIn();
    }
    private void signIn() {

        GoogleSignInClient GoogleSignInClient = buildGoogleSignInClient();
        startActivityForResult(GoogleSignInClient.getSignInIntent(), REQUEST_CODE_SIGN_IN);
    }
    private GoogleSignInClient buildGoogleSignInClient() {
        GoogleSignInOptions signInOptions =
                new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
                        .requestScopes(Drive.SCOPE_FILE)
                        .requestScopes(Drive.SCOPE_APPFOLDER)
                        .build();
        return GoogleSignIn.getClient(this, signInOptions);
    }

    private void handleSignInResult(GoogleSignInResult result) {
        android.util.Log.d(TAG, "handleSignInResult:" + result.isSuccess());
        if (result.isSuccess()) {
            // Signed in successfully, show authenticated UI.
            GoogleSignInAccount acct = result.getSignInAccount();

            android.util.Log.e(TAG, "display name: " + acct.getDisplayName());

            String personName = acct.getDisplayName();
            String personPhotoUrl = acct.getPhotoUrl().toString();
            String email = acct.getEmail();


            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Name: " + personName + ", email: " + email
                    + ", Image: " + personPhotoUrl,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


            updateUI(true);
        } else {
            // Signed out, show unauthenticated UI.
            updateUI(false);
        }
    }
    private void updateUI(boolean bl){
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),bl+"",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        // Result returned from launching the Intent from GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(...);'
        //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),requestCode+"",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();;
        GoogleSignInResult result = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInResultFromIntent(data);
        GoogleSignInAccount lastSignedInAccount = GoogleSignIn.getLastSignedInAccount(this);
        handleSignInResult(result);
        if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
             result = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInResultFromIntent(data);
            handleSignInResult(result);
        }
       mDriveClient = Drive.getDriveClient(this,lastSignedInAccount);
        // Build a drive resource client.
        mDriveResourceClient =
                Drive.getDriveResourceClient(this, lastSignedInAccount);
        fileslist();


    }
    public  void fileslist(){

        Query query = new Query.Builder()
                .addFilter(Filters.eq(SearchableField.TITLE, "example.txt"))
                .build();
        Task<MetadataBuffer> queryTask = getDriveResourceClient().query(query);
        // [END query_files]
        // [START query_results]
        queryTask
                .addOnSuccessListener(this,
                        new OnSuccessListener<MetadataBuffer>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onSuccess(MetadataBuffer metadataBuffer) {
                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"ISO",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();;
                                Log.d("SUCCESS","");
                            }
                        })
                .addOnFailureListener(this, new OnFailureListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"ORA",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();;
                        // Handle failure...
                        // [START_EXCLUDE]
                        Log.d("FAIL"+e.toString(),"");
                        //showMessage(getString(R.string.query_failed));
                        finish();
                        // [END_EXCLUDE]
                    }
                });

    }
    private DriveResourceClient getDriveResourceClient(){
        return mDriveResourceClient;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your emulator should have latest `Google Play Services` installed. Else use real Android device for testing.

Comment: i'm run on emulator but direct on my phone samsung S7 Edge

Answer (score 0):

You can try the suggested solution from this [github forum](https://github.com/googlearchive/drive-android-quickstart/issues/17) which is to enable Drive API in your Google Dev Console.

You can read more of this setup in [Java Quickstart for Drive API](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/quickstart/java#prerequisites).

Comment: I have solution after 4 hour, my SHA-1 not same thank's.